# Looking for wireless earbuds that do not stick into the ear canal

Tags: audio, earphones

I've been looking for wireless earbuds, just like the Apple model. Personally, I don't like the ones that you introduce in the ear.

And  **not in-ear**  that fill the market:

Any suggestion ?

Edit: budget around 50€.

Yes:
[image]

No:
[image]

Comment: https://www.apple.com/airpods/

Comment: They don't cost less than 50€ or $50.